# Run console size of Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, console

I'm using Pycharm to study Tensorflow.
I found that some system warnings/alarms appear long enough to the right,
but the content does not as in (1)

Some wrote increasing buffer size may help, but it didn't help me. (2)
Changing setting of "Softwrap" didn't help either.(3)

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: What version of PyCharm are you using (`Help | About`)?

Comment: Hello, this is what "About" menu shows:

Pycharm 2020.3.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-203.7148.72, build on January 27,2021
Runtime version: 11.0.9.1+11-b1145.77amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.